# Referring to Elements in an Array in a For Loop in R - beginner

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, indexing

Edit: Someone said the question is unclear, edited.

I have made a 3 dimensional array, and assigned values as follows:

```
D <- c('g', 't', NA, 'd')
nPeriods = 4
column.names = c('aaa', 'bbb')
row.names = c('jjj', 'hhh')
threeD.names = c(1:nPeriods)
E = array(c(D), dim=c(2, 2, nPeriods),
          dimnames = list(row.names, column.names, threeD.names))

values <- c(g = 5,
            t = 2,
            d = 7)

G <- apply(E, 1:3, function(x) values[x])
```

Now I want to make a for loop, to do things like:

```
for (i in 2:nPeriods){
  G[1,1,i]=G[1,1,i-1]*G[2,1,i-1]+G[2,2,i]
}
```

But I don't want to have to find the location of g, t and d each time I want to write something like this. I just want to be able to use g, t, and d if possible.

Question ends here.

---

Below is some helpful code that could possibly be adapted to find a solution?

I have this code which looks up and returns an index for each value:

```
result <- G
for (i in 2:dim(G)[3]) {
  idx <- which(E[, , 1] == 'g', arr.ind = T)
  row <- idx[1, 'row']
  col <- idx[1, 'col']
  result[row, col, i] <- result[row, col, i-1] * 2
}
```

For a simpler problem, but my real array is quite large, so writing for each element will be long. Is there a way of automating this?

They also suggested this - which is great for simple sums, but I'm not sure how it could apply to the type of sum I have above:

```
funcs <- c(g = '*', t = '+', d = '-')
modifiers <- c(g = 2, t = 3, d = 4)

G <- apply(E, 1:3, function(x) values[x])

result <- G
for (i in 2:dim(G)[3]) {
  for (j in names(values)) {
    idx <- which(E[, , 1] == j, arr.ind = T)
    row <- idx[1, 'row']
    col <- idx[1, 'col']
    result[row, col, i] <- do.call(funcs[j], args = list(result[row, col, i-1], modifiers[j]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on your stated goal, I suspect that storing your data as a set of numeric and character 3D arrays is an overcomplicated starting point. You may want to think about solutions in which your starting data can be stored as 2D matrices or data frames.

Comment: Thanks - you might be right. I have a model in which there are multiple 2d matrices, with e.g. nrow = 1, ncol = nPeriods.
Then the for loop comes in.
But what I need to do is paste together a number of theses matrices in a particular order, and then just take a slice by the period. There's probably an easier way than converting everything to arrays I guess...

Comment: There are many ways to convert matrices to data frames. You may want to learn more about "tidy" data: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification, maybe this works - get the row/column index for 'g', 't', 'd' from the `E[, , 1]`, loop over the `nPeriods` from 2, and update the 'result' by subseting the elements with a `matrix` index created with `cbind` using `gidx`, `tidx` and `didx` with `i` or `i-1` to update recursively

```
result <- G
gidx <- which(E[, , 1] == 'g', arr.ind = TRUE)
tidx <- which(E[, , 1] == 't', arr.ind = TRUE)
didx <- which(E[, , 1] == 'd', arr.ind = TRUE)
for (i in 2:nPeriods) {     
      result[cbind(gidx, i)] <- result[cbind(gidx, i-1)] * 
               result[cbind(tidx, i-1)] + result[cbind(didx, i)]
  }
```

-output

```
> result
, , 1

    aaa bbb
jjj   5  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 2

    aaa bbb
jjj  17  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 3

    aaa bbb
jjj  41  NA
hhh   2   7

, , 4

    aaa bbb
jjj  89  NA
hhh   2   7
```

-checking with OP's output

```
resultold <- G

for (i in 2:nPeriods){
  resultold[1, 1, i] <- resultold[1,1,i-1]* resultold[2,1,i-1]+resultold[2,2,i]
}

 identical(result, resultold)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This doubles every element.
I'm looking to be able to access individual elements to perform calculations on them.
e.g. 
for (i in 2:nPeriods){
  G[1,1,i]=G[1,1,i-1]*G[2,1,i-1]+G[2,2,i]
}
In an easier way.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope that helps. The 3rd and 4th blocks are example code for a simpler problem which I thought may be useful somehow in adapting to the more complicated problem.

Comment: G[1,1,i] is 'g', G[2,1,i] is 't', G[2,2,i] is 'd'.

I want something like the idx rows to index g, t, and d, so I don't have to look up the position in the array every time. I'm just hoping for something a bit more automated than the solution already given, which is correct, since my real matrix is very large.